# Сортировка выбранных значений

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте.

У меня вот какой вопрос.
Есть цикл с перебором значений. Данные из цикла выводятся в таблицу и сортируются по возрастанию.

```
if($order=="ASC"){
    $str_flg = "SORT_ASC";
}else{
    $str_flg = "SORT_DESC";
}

switch($sorter){
    case "type":
        array_multisort($task_type, constant($str_flg), SORT_REGULAR, $task_vipoln, $task_color, $task_id);
        break
}
```

Из выбранных значений есть данные, которые я бы хотел, чтобы они отображались в самом низу вывода таблицы.
Возможно ли это? Ткните, пожалуйста, в правильном направлении.

Comment: А при чем здесь mysql и js? Если данные получаются из mysql, то, может быть, там и сортировать?

В общем, можно, но для решения вашей задачи надо бы побольше информации: что за данные, какие из них должны отображаться снизу и т.д.

Comment: Посмотри usort / uasort, напишешь функцию сравнения элементов и сортируй как тебе удобно будет